# How to insert an integer into a database through command prompt

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to insert a integer into a database in C# using the code below, but everytime I run the compiler informs me that my integer is not a valid column "Invalid Column Name UserID"

Does anyone have any insight on this? Thanks.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a new User Id");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        int UserID;
        if (int.TryParse(line, out UserID))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UserID);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        //Prepare the command string
        string insertString = @"INSERT INTO tb_User(ID,f_Name, l_Name) VALUES (UserID,'Ted','Turner')";
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To answer your question regardless of your approach, try:

```
string insertString = @"INSERT INTO tb_User(ID,f_Name, l_Name) VALUES ("
+ UserID + ",'Ted','Turner')";
```

Comment: I said "regardless of your approach" geesh. Its seems he is just testing out a console app, I doubt this is an enterprise application he is writing for public consumption, yeah lets protect a console app from sql injection.

Comment: Thanks for the non-biased answer and I understand what you mean by regardless of approach. I just read that is one way to do it, but it has opportunity for so much risk. But for my small example and no knowledge on how to get it to operate, it is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, I would get into the habit of using parameterised queries, if you are not planning to use stored procedures.  In your example, I would:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tb_User(ID, f_Name, l_Name) VALUES (@id, @forename, @surname)", conn))
{
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("forename", forename);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("surname", surname);

  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Where `id`, `forename`, `surname` are the appropriate variables. Notice I am also using `using` blocks, this ensures that my objects are cleaned up after it has completed.

Answer (score 0):

it is because the 'UserID' within your insertString : ..."VALUES (UserID"... is invalid.

you need to pass a value for the UserID such as:  ..."VALUES ('myUserIDGoesHere'"...

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not dynamically reading the variables.  Use something like this:

> string insertString =
>   string.Format(@"INSERT INTO
>   tb_User(ID,f_Name, l_Name) VALUES
>   ({0},'{1}','{2}')", UserId, "Ted",
>   "Turner");

There are better ways depending on what kind of data access you're using, but this is just to make the point of how to correct the string.

Comment: Concatenating user input is very bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the first argument in `VALUES` - it simply isn't defined. If this is meant to be the value the user has entered, then you need to add a *parameter* to the command and use that parameter in the SQL; for example:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", UserID);
```

An then use

```
VALUES(@id, ...
```

in the TSQL.

Also, *generally* you might want to have the system generate the unique id. A the simplest level this could have an `IDENTITY` defined (an automatic sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameterized query:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(
        @"INSERT INTO tb_User (ID, f_Name, l_Name)
          VALUES (@ID, 'Ted', 'Turner')", connection))
    {
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID);
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```